# How to derive an average Z value among arbitrarily distributed X, Y, Z points

Tags: 3d, triangulation

I am triangulating using Delauney algorithm to create a 2D (x, y) flat surface in OpenGL. There are "control points" available, with (x,y,z) values that I need to apply to the triangulated surface to derive the z values. The derived z value needs to be "weighted" according how close the "control point" is. Before I start with brute force approach to this - any suggestion on something more elegant would help.

Comment: The "2D (x,y) surface" is "pretty much planar"? What does that mean?

Comment: "flat" would have been a better description in this case

Comment: That doesn't make it any more clear to me. If it's $2D$ (unless you're talking about curved space, which somehow this doesn't sound like) then it's flat. How can it be $2D$ and "pretty much planar/flat"?

Comment: Well, it is only 2D coordinates that are used for initial triangulation - so it is 2D - it needs to become 3D by adding control point values. The reason I mentioned planar/flat is that trilinear interpolation would probably be overkill - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation

Comment: In that case, please clarify the question. In the present formulation, "surface" unambiguously refers to the $2D$ surface, and you want to "apply" $(x,y,z)$ values to this. The entity that is "pretty much planar" is the result of this "application", not the original triangulated surface. (The result is of course also a surface, but not the surface you introduced and are thus referring back to by using the definite article.)

Comment: if it helps to clarify - original triangulated surface is flat - the resulting surface will have "elevation" data added to it.

Comment: this could be considered a sample input data - points and control points:for example - a set of random points with only 2D values
p1(3.5, -1.0, 0)
p2(-2.0, 3.6, 0)
p3(1.5, 1.2, 0)
p4(-2.3, -2.4, 0)
p5(0.3, 1.4, 0)

a set of 'control points' with 3D values - please note that the points may be outside of the triangulated surface
c1(-0.2, 1.2, 3.5)
c1(6.7, 2.3, -0.5)
c1(-10.3, 5.2, 1.5)

Comment: As I said, please clarify the question. There's an edit link underneath it. People shouldn't have to read long threads of comments to understand the question.

Comment: It's not clear whether and how the "control points" are related to the triangulation. Did you mean to imply that you have a $z$ values at every $(x,y)$ point that you used for the Delaunay [sic] triangulation? If not, why do you mention the triangulation?

Comment: Also the title says that the points are randomly distributed, but the body doesn't refer to this or specify a distribution. Perhaps you meant that the points are *arbitrarily* distributed?

Comment: 'control points' are independent of the initial point data that is used for triangulation.

Comment: Then how does the triangulation enter into the question?

Comment: edited the title of this question to reflect 'arbitrary' - if that is more concise. Triangulation creates an indice set that is used to refer to the point data when rendering. Control points are not referenced by indices, therefore not triangulated and only used to affect the z values of the points.

Comment: If I now understand the question correctly, what you're effectively asking is how to interpolate between given values of a function of two variables at arbitrary arguments -- is that correct?

Comment: it sounds like you already have an answer - let's try it!

Comment: I don't; I'm trying to establish what the question is, and you're not exactly helping.

Comment: OK - I was able to isolate a set(N count) of control points with  Z values and "weight" in a range from 0.0-1.0. How do we set the z value according to that?